# Permission Issues with Rootless Podman Container and Mapped Volume

Tags: podman

I am using a rootless Podman container to run a php+apache image.

My container setup involves mapping a directory from the host to the container (`~/foo:/var/www/html/foo`).
The user inside the container is `root`, but Apache inside the container runs as `www-data`.

If I don't set `UserNS` then the only way I can allow the `www-data` user to access the `foo` directory is to set `o+rx`.

If I set `UserNS` to `keep-id` or `keep-id:uid:33,gid:33` (33 is the uid of www-data), then Apache complains that it can't bind to port 80 (inside the container).

Is there a way to solve this issue without setting `o+rx` on the foo directory or changing the apache port?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue for my implementation.   My issue was that the source of the volume I was mapping was mounted to a network resource.   I moved the source to local file system and all issues immediately resolved.   I was pointed in this direction when I tried to use the Z option on the volume and podman was unable to set the attributes. I am rootless podman on RHEL 8.9.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/577172)

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you add `--user 0:0`?

It works for me when I add `--user 0:0` in addition to `--userns keep-id:uid=48,gid=48`.
I just tested apache (not php). Here is a demo (using rootless Podman).

1. Create *Dockerfile* with the contents:

   ```
   FROM docker.io/library/fedora
   RUN dnf -y update && dnf install -y httpd procps-ng && dnf clean all
   CMD ["/usr/sbin/httpd", "-DFOREGROUND"]
   ```
2. Build the image

   ```
   podman build -t apache .
   ```
3. Create directory *~/foo*

   ```
   mkdir ~/foo
   ```
4. Create file *~/foo/file.txt*

   ```
   echo hello > ~/foo/file.txt
   ```
5. Restrict permissions

   ```
   chmod 700 ~/foo
   chmod 700 ~/foo/file.txt
   ```
6. Start apache

   ```
   podman run --name myapache --rm -ti \
      --userns keep-id:uid=48,gid=48 \
      --user 0:0 -v ~/foo:/var/www/html/foo:Z \
      -p 8080:80 localhost/apache
   ```

   The podman command starts running. This warning is printed:

   ```
   AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.0.2.100. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
   ```
7. In another shell run

   ```
   curl localhost:8080/foo/file.txt
   ```

   This text is printed

   ```
   hello
   ```
8. Check ownership of container processes. Run command

   ```
   podman exec myapache ps axu
   ```

   The command prints the following output

   ```
   USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
   root           1  0.1  0.5  40844 10188 pts/0    Ss+  02:27   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
   apache         2  0.0  0.3  41148  6468 pts/0    S+   02:27   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
   apache         3  0.0  0.4 1135840 9056 pts/0    Sl+  02:27   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
   apache         4  0.0  0.4 1003744 8024 pts/0    Sl+  02:27   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
   apache        80  0.0  0.4 1003744 8024 pts/0    Sl+  02:27   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
   root         185  0.0  0.1   7740  3872 ?        R    02:28   0:00 ps axu
   ```

   The first container process is run by *root* but child processes are run by *apache*

***A side note***:

If `--user 0:0` is removed from the command in step 6, then
the podman command fails with the error message:

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.0.2.100. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

Comment: I think your apache is running as root inside the container... What is the output of `podman exec apa ps aux | grep httpd`

Comment: I updated the answer with the ps command.